# how to show wfs and wms sources in boundlessgeo gxp viewer

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, boundless-suite, viewer

I'm using boundlessgeo gxp viewer. I have a lot of different wms and wfs link and want to show those remote sources in my map viewer application. I have a geoserver and basic layers in it. I can add my local sources normally. What is the way of adding external wms and wfs sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For remote WMS sources the procedure is the same, but you need to make sure you have  ext override ajax from GeoExt included since the proxy needs to be used (http://geoext.org/lib/overrides/override-ext-ajax.html). If you know which WMS servers to use beforehand, you could also use a ProxyPass on your Apache webserver.

There is no real support for WFS layers in GXP, you'll need to use an gxp.plugins.OLSource and roll your own (vector layer with WFS protocol and fixed or bbox strategy etc.).

Comment: I did all ajax overrides from your link,actually I loaded  override-ext-ajax.js file before. I did all ext.ajax overrides but my new source coming null. There is no error. Code is here

Comment: defaultSourceType: "gxp_wmssource",
        sources: {
            "deneme": {
                        url: "http://api.maps.vic.gov.au/geowebcacheWM/service/wms"
                      },
            "opengeo": {
                        url: "http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms"
                       },
            ol: {
                ptype: "gxp_olsource"
            },
            google: {
                ptype: "gxp_googlesource"
            },
            osmap:{
                ptype: "gxp_osmsource"
            },...

Comment: Thanks user23054, I solved the problem through your advices.